# Strange behavior of javascript call method

Tags: javascript

I'm recently reading the "Effective javascript". In the item "Use call methods with a custom receiver". The author provides an example of adding the contents of one table to another using this method :

```
var table = {
    entries: [],
    addEntry: function(key, value) {
        this.entries.push({key: key, value: value});
    },
    forEach: function(f, thisArg) {
        var entries = this.entries;
        for (var i = 0, n = entries.length; i < n; i++)
        {
            var entry = entries[i];
            f.call(thisArg, entry.key, entry.value, i);
        }
    }
};
```

Now if I test this method writing things like:

```
table2 = table;
table1 = table;
table1.entries = [1, 3];
table1.forEach(table1.addEntry, table2);
console.log(table2.entries);
```

I get the contents of table2 entries as [1, 3, Object, Object].
Which confuses me. Why do we get those two additionnal objects. Probably, I didn't get the call method properly. Can someone explain to me what is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is

```
table2 = table;
table1 = table;
```

`table2` and `table1` refer to the same object => you are adding to the same `table` object.

You get the final two objects is because your add entry create new object:

```
{key: key, value: value}
```

Your final result looks like this:

```
[1, 3, {0:1}, {1:3}]
```

`{0:1},{1:3}`: 0,1 are the indexes

Comment: Thank you, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 1):

Both `table1` and `table2` reference to `table`, so when you call:

```
table1.entries = [1, 3];
```

it actually adds these entries to `table2` too.

To solve this, use the `new` keyword:

```
table2 = new table;
table1 = new table;
```

In addition, the reason you get something like `[1, 3, Object, Object]` instead of `[1, 3, 1, 3]` is because the `addEntry` method adds an object instead of just numbers like you did:

```
{key: key, value: value}
```

so the format of each entry is actually an object.

If you want to be able to see something meaningful instead of `Object`, stringify the entries array:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(table2.entries));
```

Comment: The `new` keyword cannot be used that way in JavaScript. For cloning, use something like `var table2 = {}, k; for (k in table) { table2[k] = table[k]; }`

Comment: Yes, I was about to ask the same thing since I got 'object is not a funtion'. Good that you clarified.

Comment: True :) I haven't notest that `table` is not a function. Though it should be in a real application

Comment: Though if you have several instances of this, the best way would be to just actually write a class (and then use `new` correctly). Cloning objects is somewhat tricky and @tom's solution is only a simple attempt (I guess that's why he said "something like").

Comment: Indeed. My simple clone is shallow and fails to create a new `entries` array. Here is an implementation using a 'class' like Alon and Ingo suggest: http://jsfiddle.net/6YTFd/